# How can I diagnose an Access violation (0xC0000005) at EIP=0x00000000?

Tags: excel, debugging, error-handling, access-violation, labview

While running a .exe in LabView 2021, I need to access an Excel file on the computer. The .exe opens the file in Excel to read from it. But, as soon as it tries to, the .exe crashes and throws the above error. It gives a possible cause, and it blames this vi.

This code has worked in the past and I have not edited it since.[image]

What could be causing this exception, specifically one at EIP=0x00000000? How can I diagnose the problem? How could I tell if it is a problem in the program code or a permissions conflict on the hosting computer?

Comment: Such an exception is always due to _a problem_ in the code.

Comment: Did you update Excel version meanwhile? Use the same Excel version on dev PC, and rebuild your code. I had similar case in the past - Microsoft updated one ActiveX method, and Invoke Node dropped run-time error.

Comment: All the invoke node inputs are required. Don't leave them without a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try using the .NET API instead of the ActiveX. It should be more stable.
Second, you have to wire all the inputs of the invoke node with a Type: Missing node.[image]